# Describing an equivalence class given a contained number.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

I have a question where I am asked to decide whether $∼$ is an equivalence relation on $\Bbb R$ where $x_1∼x_2$ means $x_1-x_2$ is an integer. I have managed to prove it is Reflexive, Symmetric and Transitive but later I am asked to "Describe $[\frac{2}{3}]$, the equivalence class containing $\frac{2}{3}$" if the relation is an equivalence relation (Which is it).I have never come across this phrase, could someone explain this to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just asking you to say what the set of elements equivalent to ${2\over 3}$ is.

For example, if we looked at the equivalence relation $\approx$ on $\mathbb{Z}$ given by $a\approx b$ iff $a^2=b^2$, we'd have $[2]=\{-2,2\}$. So:

> What numbers are $\sim{2\over 3}$?

Comment: I might be completely wrong here but would it be $\frac{2n}{3n}$, I completely understand your example but my one I'm kinda confused.

Comment: @JayVB No - $2n\over 3n$ is just $2\over 3$ (unless $n=0$ in which case it's undefined). Start small: what's another number which is $\sim{2\over 3}$?

Comment: I am looking for values such that $\frac{2}{3} - x_2$ is equal to an integer? This isn't my strongest topic.

Comment: My main issue is understanding how $[\frac{2}{3}]$ relates to the question.

Comment: @JayVB $[x]$ denotes the equivalence class of $x$. So yes, you are being asked to describe all the values which, when subtracted from $2\over 3$, yield an integer.

Comment: It just clicked with me, I have one other I attempted which is $x_1∼x_2$ means $\lfloor x_1 \rfloor = \lfloor x_2 \rfloor$ for the same $[\frac{2}{3}]$. I then went on to say what $\lfloor \frac{2}{3} \rfloor = \lfloor x_2 \rfloor$. Anything where $0 \le x \lt 1$ would suffice but this isn't a relation to $\frac{2}{3}$ so to speak is it.

Comment: @JayVB I would say it is - I think $[0, 1)$ is a perfect description of the equivalence class of $2\over 3$ under "have the same floor."

Comment: Perfect, you have been a great help to me.